# Dynamic Programming with Vectors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic, vector, monads

I'm trying to code a kind of a simple web crawler in haskell just for practice. To my own astonishment neither the web request itself nor parsing the web site was any complicated. 
I coded the program purely functional with a recursive function, but only some fourty or fifty web requests later, the program eats up all the memory.

So I tried to do the task with dynamic programming, but here I'm totally stuck, which means, I have no idea where to begin. In this tiny program I got so many errors, that I'm not able to figure out, where to start.

This is my current concept:

```
scanPage :: String -> IO (String,String,[String])
scanPage url = ....

crawler :: String -> IO [(String, Int)]
crawler startUrl = runST $ do
    toVisit <- newSTRef [startUrl] :: ST s (STRef s [String])
    visited <- newSTRef [] :: ST s (STRef s [String])
    result  <- newSTRef [] :: ST s (STRef s [(String, Int)])
    -- Iterate over urls to visit
    while (liftM not $ liftM null $ readSTRef toVisit) $ do
        url <- fmap (head) (readSTRef toVisit)            
        (moreUrls, value_a, value_b) <- scanPage url
        -- Mark page as visited
        vis <- readSTRef visited
        writeSTRef visited (url : vis)
        -- Add Results
        res <- readSTRef result
        writeSTRef result ((value_a, value_b) : res)
        -- Extend urls to visit
        nextUrls <- readSTRef toVisit
        writeSTRef toVisit (nextUrls ++ (moreUrls \\ vis))
    -- End of while
    return =<< readSTRef result

main = do
    putStrLn =<< fmap show (crawler "http://starturl.com")
```

I already wrote a lot of programs like this with arrays, which are much more convenient, as I can simply write or read from or to array elements. So I thought I could use mutable vectors for these lists, but they can't grow (at least in the same *instance*) or shrink. So I ended up with simple lists in STRef.

The first line I can't get to work is the line with the *while* command. I wrote my own while function like this

```
while :: (Monad m) => m Bool -> m a -> m ()
while cond action = do
    c <- cond
    when c $ do
        action
        while cond action
```

because I couldn't find any other while command. I googled many days for mutable vectors, but was not able to find a single tutorial or even example that I could use here. Please, can anyone tell me, how to write a syntactical correct *crawler* function? Yes, a pure functional solution would be nicer and more "haskellish", but I'm considering me still as a beginner and all this monad-stuff is still a bit strange for me. I'm willing to learn, but a hint or even an example would be really awesome.

**EDIT:**
Here comes some pseudocode of my messy code.

```
toVisitList = startURL
visitedList = []
resultList = []
while (length toVisitList /= 0) {
    url = head toVisitList   -- Get the 1st element
    toVisitList -= url       -- Remove this url from list
    visitedList += url       -- Append url to visitedList
    (moreUrls, val_a, val_b) = scanPage url
    resultList += (val_a, val_b) -- append the result
    toVisitList += (moreUrls - visitedList)
}
return resultList
```

**EDIT:**
I still haven't any clue, how to put this pseudocode into real code, especially the while-statement. Any hints appreciacted.

Comment: When recursive functions start eating up all your memory, that usually means they keep calling themselves without returning. You should, whenever possible, make them tail-recursive so they do not have this problem.

Comment: The `Control.Monad` package has `when` and `guard`, but my gut feeling here is that, if you’re not comfortable with monads yet, that’s not the best solution for you.

Comment: In fact I tried this as well, so that the last call returned the complete result, but it still keeps eating up all the memory. Nevertheless I want to understand the dynamic approach as well. An example would be really helpful.

Comment: Were each of the intermediate calls tail-recursive as well?  If you write `f [] = ""` and `f (x:xs) = (show x) ++ (f xs)`, the runtime can’t optimize any but the base case.  If you write,  `f xs = f' xs []`, `f' [] acc = acc` and `f' (x:xs) acc = f' xs (acc ++ (show x))`,  it can clean up all the temporaries.

Comment: What "dynamic approach" do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The natural data structure for your `toVisitList` is a *queue*. There are a few implementations of queues around, but for this purpose, the simplest thing is to just use `Data.Sequence.Seq`. This lets you add things to the end with `|>` or `<>`, and to view the beginning with `viewl`. Consider something like

```
crawlOnce :: Seq Url -> [Url] -> IO (Either [Url] (Seq Url, [Url]))
```

`crawlOnce toVisitList visitedList` uses `viewl` to look at the front of the list of URLs to visit. If it's empty, it returns `Left visitedList`. Otherwise, it visits the first URL, appends it to the visited list, and adds the newly discovered URLS to the list to visit, then wraps them up in `Right`.

There are several reasonable variations. For instance, you could go for a type like `ExceptT [Url] (StateT (Seq Url, [Url]) IO) a` that "throws" its final result.

Comment: A sequence sounds great. There are so many classes to explore... Is there a kind of table or map with all that useful classes grouped by function?

Comment: @Hennes, for *classes* (not relevant here), there's Typeclassopedia. For basic libraries, you might want to look at what's included in the Haskell Platform, whether or not you actually decide to *install* the Platform.

Comment: Shouldn't we use a set? How can we filter out duplicates with a queue?

Comment: @rubik, good point! We should probably have both, using the set to represent the visited list and using it to filter which things are added to the queue.

Comment: Come on, don't let me fall on my knees begging for a simple working example for this task. I really spent this entire day googling for some help but found nothing. It would help me a lot to understand all this.

Comment: @Hennes, last night I was out a-wooing, and I have plans this afternoon. Perhaps this evening I'll have time. You may want to check out the #haskell IRC channel for live help.

Comment: Seems to be a lot more difficult than expected, huh?

Comment: @Hennes, nope. Just haven't had a chance to work it up.